# what does this symbol mean on intellij and how can I fix it

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

All the dirs have the following symbol - [image]

And all the java classes inside these directories have this symbol

[image]

How can I fix this to make everything back to normal?

Comment: Doesn't it mean "j" for Java? Why is it a problem?

Comment: Looks like you opened a java file inside a non-java project

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the folder, where the `.java` file is located in is not added as a source folder. To do this, go to `File | Project Structure | Modules`. If you have several modules, select the one in which the folder you want to add as source folder is located.

Then, on the right side you can see a list of folders. Select the one which contains the java files and click on mark as: Sources (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).